# $http.get with 2 parameter in ionic framework (angularjs)

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have my $http.get with one parameter, and it works like :

```
getUserBand: function(email) {
        return $http.get(baseUrl + 'selectUserBand.php?email=' + email);
    },
```

I want to send 2 parameter like :

```
getUserBand: function(email,param2) {
        How to call 2 parameter in this field?
    },
```

How to call email and param2 in the $http.get field?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can append param with '&':

```
getUserBand: function(email,param2) {    
  $http.get(baseUrl + 'selectUserBand.php?email=' + email + '&param2=' + param2);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Store all your url params in an object like,

```
var urlParams = {
    'param1': email,
    'param2': username
},
```

now make the request using the following code,

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'url from which you want to get',
    params: urlParams //which will be automatically turned to ?key1=value1&key2=value2 after the url 
})
```