# Angular - combine multiple text inputs after a get http url

Tags: angularjs, url, ionic-framework, get

Asked variations on this question in a few places and read EVERYTHING on Google so I'm fairly certain this can't be done. But thought I would ask here one last time.

I want to append a GET $HTTP URL with a number of text input params.

For example

Date 1 textinput, day, month, year, 
+00
+'-'
Date 2 textinput, day, month, year, 
+00
+'-'

= 1101201700-2101201700

This is the code I have so far and it works up to the point of adding whatever I type to the url, but as soon as I add another input field it fails saying the second input is undefined.

Any ideas? Want to keep it simple too ideally...

```
   .controller("DateCtrl", function ($scope, $stateParams, dateService) {
$scope.events = dateService.getEvents($stateParams.date).then(function (events) {
    $scope.events = events;
    console.log("Date Controller1 says: Hello World - I also work");

});
```

factory....

```
     .factory('dateService', function ($http) {
    var events = [];

    return {
        getEvents: function (date, date2) {
            var params = {
                date:date,
                date2:date2
            }


            return $http.get('url' + "&" + params.date + "-" + params.date2).then(function (response) {
                events = response.data.events;
                return response.data.events;
            });
        },
```

state...

```
  .state('date', {
    url: "/date/:date/:date2",
    templateUrl: "templates/Date.html",
    controller: "DateCtrl"
})
```

html...

```
       <input type="text" placeholder="bla1" class="form-control" ng-model="date"/>
<input type="text" placeholder="bla1" class="form-control" ng-model="date2" />

<a ui-sref="date({date:date,date2:date2})">Go</a>
```

EDIT:

The url i want to call is an external one, not a page within the app.

This is close [$http.get with 2 parameter in ionic framework (angularjs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30709772/http-get-with-2-parameter-in-ionic-framework-angularjs)

But I'm not sure what I'm doing with the controller since in my code I have to scope a param.

EDIT 2:

this now works except that date2 is showing as "undefined" in the url string...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to perform a GET request and have more than one param passed into your request. This can be done in the following format:

```
$http.get('yoururl/:param1/:param2')
```

You can stack params using that syntax (as long as the URL does not exceed 2,000 characters), but you will need to make sure there is a '/' to divide each param you are passing in, otherwise it will come back as undefined. If you want to pass in an ambiguous number of params because you will not consistently be passing in the same amount, you can have one param and use:

```
JSON.stringify(object)
```

to pass in an object that can then be parsed on the other side to query from.

EDIT:

The code above is for defining your routes. What you're looking for is a bit different than my answer. You need is a way of defining the URL as you are calling it.

Try the following format:

```
var params = {
  date1: 'value1',
  date2: 'value2
}

$http.get('yoururl/' + params.date1 + '/' + params.date2)
```

This will insert the values of the object into the URL.

Comment: AHH! I tried the stacking but I didn't include the "/"....I'll give it a try - thank you!

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately. It's doing the same error I encountered a few times with variations of this idea - its including the text "date1" "date2" but not the text that is input into the field.

Comment: GET requests don't take data in a separate parameter - they should be straight in the URL request. Unless urlr& is doing g something I'm unaware of, the way you are passing in your params with a comma and then an object is the format for a POST. You need to format your GET as I did above where they are within the url string being requested.

Comment: So, what I want is to call web API and display data from a range of dates. These dates are set by the user via the input fields. However, when I did what you suggested, it literally appended the "param1/:param2" etc to the url. I don't know why. I'm new to ionic so im sure its a simple error - assuming it can be done of course, but as it is I can't seem to bind the input values to the params, and then append said params to the url. Also, I haven't scoped the second param in the controller, which i think is one of the problems, but i'm not how you "stack params" in the controller.

Comment: Ahh I just updated my answer to reflect what I think you're looking for. Check it out and let me know if that gets you going.

Comment: So close...if i do  return {
            getEvents: function (date, date2) {
                var params = {
                    date:date,
                    date2:date2
                }                                                                                                                   and then URL + "&" + params.date + "-" + params.date2)                                   it returns the first inputed date but the second is "undefined". I feel like thats something to do with my controller, as it changes when I tweak the "stateparams" code. Thanks for your help by the way!!

Comment: Your ng-model on the HTML is only for date. Do you have anything bound to date2? If not, you're not going to be setting a value for it to pass in

Comment: Easy way to find where the error lies is to set your var params = { date: date, date2: 'hardcoded'}. This will let you know if your controller is not getting a value passed in, or if your factory / state is not reading the value by still returning undefined

Comment: Sorry I left it showing the old code, Ive just updated my question. Ok so when I swap over date and date 2, after the "function" in the factory, whichever is the second, always comes back 'undefined' in the url....is there a problem with my syntax?   return {
            getEvents: function (date, date2) {
                var params = {
                    date:date,
                    date2:date2
                }